# File is opened but not written to

Tags: c, printf

I read many sites, tried all possible solutions, but code opens the file, but doesnt write the fprintf line, any help is appreciated

```
int Function(){
  FILE *outputtfilepointer;

  outputtfilepointer = fopen("output.csv", "w"); 
  fprintf(outputtfilepointer,"Iteration,5,6,%d,%f\n",5,0.6);    

  fclose (outputtfilepointer);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is C code, not C++. Your C++ tag is wrong.

Comment: It's also C++ (I just compiled it with my C++ compiler, and it works correctly for me)

Comment: then what may be another reason? i tried many times

Comment: The only thing I can think of is maybe your filesystem is full?  Seems unlikely though.

Comment: i open 10 csv files, this is one of them, can this full thing happen?

Comment: @user1450005 Check that `fopen` is not returning a null pointer.

Comment: `fopen` returns NULL and sets `errno` on failure. You should be able to determine the error.

Comment: Please edit the question and improve it by telling which operating system, file system, compiler, compilation flags you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the documentation of [fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) and of [fprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3.html)? These functions could fail, and you should test that:

```
int Function(){
  FILE *outputtfilepointer = fopen("output.csv", "w"); 
  if (!outputfilepointer) { perror("fopen"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
  if (fprintf(outputtfilepointer,"Iteration,5,6,%d,%f\n",5,0.6)<0)
     { perror("fprintf"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };  
  if (fclose (outputtfilepointer)) 
     { perror("fclose"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
  return 0; 
}
```

Testing failure of `fopen` is required (that does happen easily). Many people
(me included) are lame so don't bother testing failure of `fprintf` and `fclose`, since it is less common.

You'll need a `#include <stdlib.h>` for `exit`

Of course, read the documentation of *every function* that you are using, e.g. also [fclose(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fclose.3.html), [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html), [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html)

Notice the minimal pattern to handle error cases: print using `perror` (to *stderr*) an `errno`  related message then `exit`. Many serious programs are doing more sophisticated things (e.g. using `strerror(errno)` and `longjmp` in some error handler ...)

BTW, you should compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`) and **use the debugger** (`gdb`). On Linux you might also use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), [ltrace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html)

Comment: thanks much, tested, still opens the file i am sure, since modified time of file has been changed, but doesnt write the line inside file

Comment: funny thing is, i use the same code in another function, and it opens file, and writes to file, but in this function, it doesnt work

Comment: Yes it does. BTW, which operating system, file-system, compiler, optimization flags are you using? Please edit your question to improve it!

Comment: added your code, doesnt exit, so ifs return trues i suppose, i really wonder what is going on